# Escape (Insert backslash) before brackets in a Python string

Tags: python, escaping

I need to format many strings that contain a similar structure:

```
 u'LastName FirstName (Department / Subdepartment)'
```

My wish is to get the string to look like this:

```
 u'LastName FirstName \(Department / Subdepartment\)'
```

Meaning I need to add a backslash to the opening bracket and to the closing bracket.

So far I am doing this in Python:

```
  displayName = displayName.replace('(', '\(').replace(')', '\)').
```

Which seems OK, but I am just wondering:

Is there is a more Pythonic way to do it?

I did not find a proper way [Python's String documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), but maybe I am looking in the wrong place...

Comment: Try re.escape(string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already found the most Pythonic way, *regex* provides a not so readable solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'LastName FirstName (Department / Subdepartment)'
>>> print re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', s)
LastName FirstName \(Department / Subdepartment\)
```

Comment: When I try this I get: `LastName FirstName \\(Department / Subdepartment\\)`so not one, but two backslashes.

Comment: @Parsa You may have confused the string `repr` with the actual printed string. Example. `>>> re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', s)`
`u'LastName FirstName \\(Department / Subdepartment\\)'`
`>>> print(re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', s))`
`LastName FirstName \(Department / Subdepartment\)`. So try just adding `print(....)` and you'll see it works

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`re.escape('string')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).

example:

```
import re

escaped = re.escape(u'LastName FirstName (Department / Subdepartment)')
```

Note:
This method will return the string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed which includes punctuation and white-space.

Though that may be useful for you.

Comment: what if the string has other regex metacharacters in it like `.`? They will be escaped to `\.`

Comment: If he needs to escape the brackets I am assuming that other such escapes might be useful. I may be wrong however.

Comment: @Serdalis, I would have used `re`, but I need to escape only the brackets, because this string going to LDAP query. So only the brackets need to be escaped.

Comment: @Serdalis, on the other hand, I know for sure, I will not have dots inside, so I could use your methods

Comment: this removes spaces, sometimes u want to keep the space

Comment: @Kay Spaces are counted as non-alphanumeric, so yes, but maybe the answer doesn't make that clear enough, i'll make it more explicit.