# Snakemake special symbol in wildcard

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

I have Snakamake rule as follows, where my wildcard contains special characters, so I escape them using sub, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915837/escape-insert-backslash-before-brackets-in-a-python-string/16915928?noredirect=1#comment108540217_16915928). Output file: `data/extract_AAV(1).csv`.

```
import re
rule get_data:
    input:
    output: "data/extract_{re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', filename)}.csv"
    shell: "python get_data.py --filename {re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', wildcards.filename)}"
```

However, I get an error as follows:

> module 're' has no attribute 'sub(r'('

Running the re module works fine in Python:

```
filename = 'extract_AAV(1).csv'
print(re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', filename)
# returns: extract_AAV\\(1\\).csv
```

A reproducible example of the error when passing wildcards with special characters from Snakemake to a python script is as follows:

Snakemake file:

```
rule get_data:
     output: "extract_{sample}.csv"
     shell: "python run.py --fn {wildcards.sample}"
```

run.py

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--fn', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
df.to_csv("extract_"+args.fn+'.csv')
```

command to execute attempt 1:

```
$ snakemake extract_AAV(1).csv --cores 1
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

command to execute attempt 2:

```
$ snakemake extract_AAV\(1\).csv --cores 1
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       get_data
        1

[Wed Apr 29 11:31:34 2020]
rule get_data:
    output: extract_AAV(1).csv
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sample=AAV(1)
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `set -euo pipefail;  python run.py --fn AAV(1)'
[Wed Apr 29 11:31:34 2020]
Error in rule get_data:
    jobid: 0
    output: extract_AAV(1).csv
    shell:
        python run.py --fn AAV(1)
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /home/XXXXX/.snakemake/log/2020-04-29T113134.773987.snakemake.log
```

Comment: Souldn't that be an f-string?

Comment: First, remove the empty `input:` section. Next: what does the `filename` means in the context of the expression inside the output section?

Comment: Hi @DmitryKuzminov filename is a wildcard which fulfills: `extract_{filename}.csv` but this wildcard contains special characters `(` and `)`

Comment: @Parsa, the example is unclear to me. The output of a rule is "fixed" in the sense that it is a string that can contain wildcards, but it can not have logic such regex substitutions. Probably what you want to do is change a rule upstream of get_data to escape the wildcard, and this will get passed along in the wildcards. Although I am not sure if escaped characters are passed correctly between rules. As a slightly unconstructive side-note: you really shouldn't be putting special characters in your input or wanting to propagate them.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Thanks for your advice. I agree with not including wildcards in filenames, but often in a larger team of developers decisions have been made in the past about the structure and organisation of files which cannot be easily changed. Given the complications, it seems like Snakemake isn't the best tool to address this problem. Thanks to Dimitry also

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to escape symbols in wildcards in your case. Moreover, the wildcard is just an identifier, no expressions are allowed. The script below illustrates how to produce the file `data/extract_AAV(1).csv`:

```
rule all:
    input: "data/extract_AAV(1).csv"

rule get_data:
    output: "data/extract_AAV({index}).csv"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

From my experience there may be a problem with spaces or quotes if they are used in filenames. For example, if the filename contains a whitespace, you need to put it in quotes in the CLI command:

```
rule all:
    input: "data/extract_AAV (1).csv"

rule get_data:
    output: "data/extract_AAV ({index}).csv"
    shell: "touch \"{output}\""
```

Comment: Hi Dimitry, if you the case in the question - passing the wildcard as a python argument then special characters in the wildcard must be escaped.

Comment: @Parsa, didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @Dimitry updated to clarify, in particular `A reproducible example of the error when passing wildcards with special characters from Snakemake to a python script is as follows`

Comment: @Parsa, that is a problem of argparse. It fails if you run your scripts like that: `python run.py --fn AAV(1)`, but it's ok to put the argument into quotes: `python run.py --fn "AAV(1)"`. My solution should work: `shell: "python run.py --fn \"{output}\""`

Comment: @Dimitry excellent thank you, I will run some tests tomorrow morning and approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

Either I cannot reproduce the problem or you are making things more complicated than necessary. This works for me:

```
samples = ['AAV(1)', 'AAV(2)']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('data/extract_{sample}.csv', sample= samples),

wildcard_constraints:
    sample= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in samples]),

rule one:
    output:
        'data/extract_{sample}.csv'
    shell:
        r"""
        touch '{output}'
        """
```

(The `wildcard_constraints` bit is not necessary here but I tend to use it quite liberally).

If this doesn't help, can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi dariober, if you run the code in my question it runs fine for you? Could you advise which version of Snakemake & python you're using and I'll try re-running with the same as your system.

Comment: snakemake 5.5.0 and python 3.6 here. Yes, I can reproduce the error with your code. But what I meant in my answer is that I don't have any issue with wildcards containing special characters. If my suggestion doesn't work for you say why and maybe we can help.